# Why should we use buffer before sending it into functions

Tags: c, function, buffer

I've read this and I only know that buffer is unspecified length of data in RAM

```
    char buf[100];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.txt", "abc");
    FILE *f = fopen(buf, "r");
```

How does it work?
Why should we use buffer for an argument in a function?
And why doesn't

```
    char buf[100] = "abc.txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(buf, "r");
```

work?

Comment: Why second one doesn't work ?

Comment: It appears that the length of the buffer *is* specified, it is `100` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the latter way will work as well. However in many cases you need to form the filename at a run time, which means you have to use `snprintf()` (you are *not* using `sprintf()`, are you?) to build the filename. For example, this might look like this:

```
int user_id = get_user_id();
char fname[PATH_MAX];
/* for each user data is in a file <user_id>.txt */
snprintf(fname, sizeof(fname), "%d.txt", user_id);
fp = fopen(fname, "r");
```

In your (very simple case), you can do it even simpler:

```
fp = fopen("abc.txt", "r")
```